# c# ninject inject dependency in a instantiated class

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have a `C# MVC` project using `Repository Pattern` and `Ninject` (DI). All is working fine.

Inside a Repository Im instantiating a class to process some calls to external APIs like this:

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository
    {
        private readonly AppState _appState;

        public EmployeeRepository(IAppStateProvider appStateProvider)
        {
            _appState = appStateProvider.AppState;
        }

        public bool ProcessEmployee(long employeeId, object data)
        {
            var api = new ExternalAPI(_appState);
            api.PostData(data);
            return true;
        }
}
```

Then my `ExternalAPI.cs` class is:

```
public class ExternalAPI: BaseRepository
    {
        [Inject]
        public ILogRepository Logger { get; set; }

        private readonly AppState _appState;

        public ExternalAPI(AppState appState)
        {
            _appState = appState;
        }


        private bool PostData(object data)
        {
            bool returnVal = true;

            // Some code here....

            Logger.InsertLog(data); // HERE Logger IS NULL

            return returnVal;
        }
 }
```

I get an exception here because `Logger` is `null`.

And in my main project `NinjectWebCommon.cs` file Im registering the dependency correctly:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {

            kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogRepository)).To(typeof(Data.LogRepository));
         }
```

> Any clue why the `[Inject]` of `ILogRepository` is not working in the `ExternalAPI` class?

Maybe because from EmployeeRepository Im creating a new instance of that class:

```
var api = new ExternalAPI(_appState);
```

> Any advice and how can I make the injection of `ILogRepository` work in `ExternalAPI` class?

Comment: The DI container can only inject values if the DI container is asked to create the instance. Otherwise how should it knows when an instance is created? There is no magic star dust

Comment: BTW A property for injection should be treated as an optional one. If it is required inject it through constructor.

Comment: So you recommend me to register as dependency the ExternalAPI class and create its corresponding interface so I can inject it in EmployeeRepository and then Inject will work right ?

Comment: So whenever you have a class that you might instantiate and in case you want to inject something there you will have to register that class and make it DI compatible correct?

Comment: No, whenever you want the DI container to inject then you have to ask the DI container for the instance. Whenever you create a new instance „by hand“ (as you do with *new ExternalAPI(...)* ) you have to take care for injecting values by yourself.

Comment: Do you have a sample code just to get it please. Appreciate jt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference [Explicit Dependencies Principle](https://deviq.com/explicit-dependencies-principle/)

> Methods and classes should explicitly require (typically through method parameters or constructor parameters) any collaborating objects they need in order to function correctly.

`ExternalAPI` is dependent on `ILogRepository` and `AppState` so that is what should be injected into it

```
public class ExternalAPI: BaseRepository, IExternalAPI {

    private readonly ILogRepository logger;
    private readonly AppState _appState;

    public ExternalAPI(IAppStateProvider appStateProvidere, ILogRepository logger) {
        _appState = appStateProvidere.AppState;
        this.logger = logger;
    }


    public bool PostData(object data) {
        bool returnVal = true;

        // Some code here....

        logger.InsertLog(data); // HERE Logger IS NULL

        return returnVal;
    }
}
```

`EmployeeRepository` is dependent on `ExternalAPI` so that is what should be injected into it.

```
public class EmployeeRepository : IEmployeeRepository {
    private readonly IExternalAPI api;

    public EmployeeRepository(IExternalAPI api) {
        this.api = api;
    }

    public bool ProcessEmployee(long employeeId, object data) {
        api.PostData(data);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Ensure that any necessary dependencies are registered with the container

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel) {
    //...
    kernel.Bind(typeof(ILogRepository)).To(typeof(Data.LogRepository));
    kernel.Bind(typeof(IExternalAPI)).To(typeof(ExternalAPI));
    //...
 }
```